# My JTextArea continues on for infinity, despite adding a LineWrap etc

Tags: java, swing

package swingtraining;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Color.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.TEAL;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

public MyFrame(){


    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
};

public static class MyPanel extends JPanel{

public MyPanel(){

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    setBackground(BLACK);
    setOpaque(true);

    GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc1.insets = new Insets(200,0,0,200);
    gbc1.ipadx = 100;
    gbc1.ipady = 100;
    gbc1.gridx = 1;
    gbc1.gridy = 1;

    gbc2.insets = new Insets(0,200,200,0);
    gbc2.ipadx = 150;
    gbc2.ipady = 10 ;
    gbc2.gridx = 1;
    gbc2.gridy = 1;

    JTextArea jta1 = new JTextArea();

    jta1.setLineWrap(true);
    jta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JButton jb1 = new JButton("Have a banana!");

    jb1.setToolTipText("Button prints Banana.");

    ActionListener action1 = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            System.out.println("\nBananas!");

        }
    };


    jb1.addActionListener(action1);



    add(jta1,gbc2);
    add(jb1,gbc1);


    };



};

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                MyFrame jf1 = new MyFrame();
                MyPanel jp1 = new MyPanel();
                jf1.add(jp1);

            }
        });
    }   
}
```

The code is just a simple JFrame, Panel, with a Button that prints bananas, and a JTextArea. When typed into without the LineWrap etc, it simply extends itself depending on which direction input is being applied. (pressing enter to go down in the area pulls it upwards/downwards, and typing into it pulls it to the left and to the right, making it bigger.) This makes sense, I didn't add a LineWrap or anything. However, adding those;

```
jta1.setLineWrap(true);
jta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

I get the following result;

Just a picture to show what I'm talking about:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMYtm.png]

What I'm aiming for is a JTextArea that has limits, when those are exceeded creates a scrollbar, and doesn't change size at all.

Suggestions?

Comment: In the future post a picture of the frame so it is easier to see the detail. The whole desktop is not relevant. And don't forget to "accept" answers when you get help by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved. You have asked several questions, but not once have you accepted an answer.

Comment: Yea sorry, I'll be mindful, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm aiming for is a JTextArea that has limits, when those are exceeded creates a scrollbar, and doesn't change size at all.

```
JTextArea jta1 = new JTextArea();
```

Your text area doesn't have preferred size so it keeps growing. You need to create the text area with a preferred size. This is done by using:

```
JTextArea jta1 = new JTextArea(5, 30);
```

Now the layout manager can use the preferred size of the text area and the scrollpane will display the scrollbars when the preferred size of the text area is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

> when those are exceeded creates a scrollbar, and doesn't change size at all.

And as pointed out by MadProgrammer if you want a scrollbar then you also need to actually add your text area to a JScrollPane and then add the scrollpane to the frame. So you would also need to use code like:

```
//add(jta1,gbc2);
add(new JScrollPane(jta1), gbc);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Add add the `JTextArea` to a `JScrollPane` ;)

Comment: How can this JScrollPane be added? Can I have an example using my code as context? : D

Comment: @Codster, `Can I have an example ` still waiting for you to accept answers from the other questions you have asked.

Comment: Sorry lol just set a lot of my questions to answered actually, didn't realize that xD

Comment: @Codster, answer updated with single line of code needed to use a scroll pane.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. Cheers!